# Is there a drug problem within Bob's Burgers?

Tags: analysis, bobs-burgers

So, this is an odd question due to the nature of the show, but I've noticed that Bob's Burgers has made reference to abusing pain killers more than once.

1. Bob has to take pain killers during the burger boss episode. He ends up using them liberally. "Better take one more just in case" I believe he says at one point. The episode ends up with Bob getting whacked out on pain killers and chasing some bully kids because he thinks they're from the game.
2. Bob gets high from pain killers in the episode where the family goes to a beach house to help Teddy. The Belchers end up going inside the house and start messing around when eventually Bob falls and hurts his back. When the home owner arrives, she gives Bob some pain killers and keeps giving him pills during their stay. When they drive away, Bob asks for more pills and the home owner gives him more.
3. Sargent Bosco says, "I like to take pills; the bad kind that make you feel good" during the speed dating episode.
4. Bob breaks his leg in "The Wolf of Wharf Street" and after taking pain killers, thinks Teddy is a werewolf (thanks to DForck42 for this one)

There are 2 more occurrences, but I seem to have forgotten them now that I'm writing the question.

So, is there deeper meaning behind this? Is it possible one (or more) of the writers or maybe someone else related to the show deliberately tries to emphasise substance abuse? I mean, it's funny to see Bob high, but it seems too coincidental.

Comment: Three to five instances over 150 episodes is anecdotal, and obviously just a case of "ooh this will be funny".

Comment: Coincidental? What is? You do know how many shows, even animated ones have drug references? This isn't the only one and I'd say that other Fox show, Family Guy has even more.

Comment: Good points. I understand many shows have drug references, but as I stated, I found it odd due to the nature of the show. Bob's Burgers is not at all comparable to Family Guy. I'd expect nothing less from Family Guy. Family Guy has a rating of TV-14 and raunchy content is the norm while Bob's Burgers is a TV-PG and so far (from my recollection) has not had any raunchy content. Hence why the "substance abuse" pops out at me.

Comment: there's also the halloween special where bob thinks teddy is a werewolf